# Communication between android phone and Raspberry Pi over WiFi without external modem/router?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, wifi, p2p, wifi-direct

I want to control Raspberry Pi 3 with an android application via WiFi, without external modem/router/...

This application needs to do the followings:

- send commands to RPi
- send/receive files to/from RPi

So far, I have setup RPi as a ***wireless access point***, and I'm able to find RPi in my android phone via WiFi and connect to it.

But the question is how can I communicate with it after being connected !?

Firstly, I thought using SSH. I tried some ready apps like JuiceSSH. And it was successful. I was able to SSH into RPi and execute commands.

But then I thought maybe there's no need to SSH. Because the RPi itself is a wireless access point, and my android phone is connected to it.

Now here is my question:

***Are there any methods (other than SSH) to send commands to RPi or send/receive files to/from RPi after connecting to it !? If so, how can I implement it?***

Any sample codes or examples are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Of course. You can run a webserver on the pi. And connect from android device with any browser or an app you write to do so. Further you can let run your own -server-socket server on the pi and communicate with it using your client socket app on android.

Comment: You can also start an FTP server on the pi to exchange files.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps for your comments. Right now, the RPi is setup as access point, and android device is connected to it over wifi. Is this enough? Simply, I want to send a command, `mycommand` to RPi to be executed there. How can I do this ?

Comment: Please give an example of such a command. And further... Did you really read my comment?

Comment: @greenapps the command could be any linux command to control RPi. For example `sudo python mycode.py` to execute a python script. And yes I read your comment carefully. I want to develop the android app, because it usually has better graphics and UI than RPi side

Comment: Use SSH for such commands.

Comment: @greenapps That's exactly what I want to know: whether to implement SSH, or use other protocols ? Can I send/receive files with SSH too ? And which SSH do you recommend? jsch or other ?

Comment: This is a programming site. Not a site to talk about SSH commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a point of not using SSH merely because RPI act as as Wireless access point. Anyways if it's a basic Shell access you need to the RPI from the phone, SSH or Telnet can be easy to setup.

If you are in capacity to implement your own server inside the RPI by code and do something inside the code, gRPC can come handy, given it's available in many languages.

Ex: gRPC server in the RPI, gRPC client in the android app. Basically gives simple client-server system.

There are many other ways to achieve the same thing, depending on your exact requirements and constraints.

Or you can simply start a webserver inside the RPI and use the browser in the phone to access it. This seems more simple and robust.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Python-Web-Server-for-your-Raspberry-Pi/
http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Android-App-communication/

Comment: Thanks @nowaconcordia for your answer. I don't want to create a webserver in RPi. I prefer using an android app, because it has more features in graphics and UI.

Comment: You can still implement a webserver to provide an API (ex. REST etc), so the app can make requests and interact.

Comment: Can I send commands from android phone to RPi with this structure? For example linux commands like `sudo python mycode.py` to be run on RPi ?

Comment: Yep. Maybe in conjunction with something like java process builder you can achieve what you want. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/

https://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/